# What can I do to fix ImageMagick in Catalina?

Tags: linux, bash, homebrew, imagemagick, macos-catalina

I tried to check installations of ImageMagick then brew. In a classic case of knowing just enough to cause trouble the diagnoses are more complicated than I know how to treat. Hoping for a second opinion from specialists here. Apologies for the long record but I don't even know what to pull for you. Please note that I don't even understand the correct syntax for my bash so complete commands are appreciated. Likewise when there are multiple lines of command. It might be talking about my attempt to fix brew's $PATH, likely also made worse. It seems what I lack in knowledge I make up for in blind courage.

```
pamela@MBP ~ % which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
pamela@MBP ~ % sudo port install imagemagick
Password:
sudo: port: command not found
pamela@MBP ~ % install imagemagick
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
pamela@MBP ~ % brew info imagemagick
==> imagemagick: stable 7.1.0-60, HEAD
Tools and libraries to manipulate images in many formats
https://imagemagick.org/index.php
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.0-60 (807 files, 30.9MB) *
  Built from source on 2023-02-03 at 23:53:34
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/imagemagick.rb
License: ImageMagick
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: freetype ✔, ghostscript ✔, jpeg-turbo ✔, libheif ✔, liblqr ✔, libpng ✔, libraw ✔, libtiff ✔, libtool ✔, little-cms2 ✔, openexr ✔, openjpeg ✔, webp ✔, xz ✔, libomp ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 2,361 (30 days), 350,550 (90 days), 1,832,708 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,118 (30 days), 310,391 (90 days), 1,624,862 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
pamela@MBP ~ % brew doctor
-sudo brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@3.10

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew/homebrew-core.
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
  cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash -u && git clean -d -f

Uncommitted files:
  ?? Formula/.DS_Store

You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew/homebrew-cask.
If this is a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
  cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask && git stash -u && git clean -d -f

Uncommitted files:
   D Casks/betterzip.rb

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
  /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
pamela@MBP ~ % -sudo brew doctor
zsh: command not found: -sudo
pamela@MBP ~ % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core && git stash -u && git clean -d -f
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: ef581d016dd field3d: deprecate
pamela@MBP homebrew-core % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask && git stash -u && git clean -d -f
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 77cb58db83 Update downie from 4.6.7,4515 to 4.6.7,4516 (#140574)
pamela@MBP homebrew-cask % brew cleanup
/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/aom/3.4.0... (23 files, 13.7MB)
Warning: Skipping apr: most recent version 1.7.2 not installed
Warning: Skipping apr-util: most recent version 1.6.3 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/2022-04-26... (3 files, 215.6KB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/2022-07-19... (3 files, 222.6KB)
Warning: Skipping curl: most recent version 7.87.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping expat: most recent version 2.5.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping fdk-aac-encoder: most recent version 1.0.3 not installed
Warning: Skipping homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg: most recent version 5.1.2-with-options_1 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.14.0... (84 files, 2.3MB)
Warning: Skipping freeglut: most recent version 3.4.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping freetds: most recent version 1.3.17 not installed
Warning: Skipping gd: most recent version 2.3.3_4 not installed
Warning: Skipping gdk-pixbuf: most recent version 2.42.10 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.21... (1,953 files, 19.0MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.2... (449 files, 20.6MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.72.2_1... (432 files, 20.2MB)
Warning: Skipping gnu-getopt: most recent version 2.38.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping gobject-introspection: most recent version 1.74.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping gpac: most recent version 2.2.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping harfbuzz: most recent version 6.0.0_1 not installed
Warning: Skipping icu4c: most recent version 72.1 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/imath/3.1.5... (49 files, 924.9KB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/jasper/3.0.4... (44 files, 1.5MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/jasper/3.0.6_1... (44 files, 1.5MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg-turbo/2.1.4... (44 files, 3.8MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg-xl/0.6.1... (61 files, 17.7MB)
Warning: Skipping krb5: most recent version 1.20.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping libass: most recent version 0.17.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping libavif: most recent version 0.11.1 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libde265/1.0.10... (21 files, 1.6MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libde265/1.0.8... (22 files, 2.3MB)
Warning: Skipping libffi: most recent version 3.4.4 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libheif/1.12.0_1... (25 files, 2.9MB)
Warning: Skipping libidn2: most recent version 2.3.4_1 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libnghttp2/1.47.0... (13 files, 679KB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libomp/14.0.6... (7 files, 1.6MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37... (27 files, 1.2MB)
Warning: Skipping libpq: most recent version 15.1 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libraw/0.20.2_2... (73 files, 5.6MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.4.0... (249 files, 4.5MB)
Warning: Skipping libunistring: most recent version 1.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping libvpx: most recent version 1.12.0 not installed
Warning: Skipping libx11: most recent version 1.8.3 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxau: most recent version 1.0.11 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxdamage: most recent version 1.1.6 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxdmcp: most recent version 1.1.4 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxext: most recent version 1.3.5 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxml2: most recent version 2.10.3_2 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxrandr: most recent version 1.5.3 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxrender: most recent version 0.9.11 not installed
Warning: Skipping libxxf86vm: most recent version 1.1.5 not installed
Warning: Skipping libzip: most recent version 1.9.2 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.13.1... (21 files, 1.3MB)
Warning: Skipping mesa: most recent version 22.3.4 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/nasm/2.15.05... (29 files, 2.9MB)
Warning: Skipping openldap: most recent version 2.6.3 not installed
Warning: Skipping openslide: most recent version 3.4.1_7 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1q... (8,097 files, 18.5MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/pcre2/10.40... (230 files, 6.4MB)
Warning: Skipping php: most recent version 8.2.1_1 not installed
Warning: Skipping pixman: most recent version 0.42.2 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1... (3,086 files, 55.8MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.1.2... (48 files, 1.6MB)
Warning: Skipping sdl2: most recent version 2.26.2 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.39.2... (11 files, 4.4MB)
Warning: Skipping texinfo: most recent version 7.0.2 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.2... (41 files, 2.5MB)
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.3... (41 files, 2.5MB)
Warning: Skipping xorgproto: most recent version 2022.2 not installed
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.5_1... (95 files, 1.4MB)
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
pamela@MBP homebrew-cask % /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins
pamela@MBP homebrew-cask %
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Based on the output here a lot of newer versions aren't installed. I'm not at all convinced this can be fixed at all with Catalina - current brew version [requires Big Sur or higher](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation). Since this is a very much MacOS-related issue it might fare better in the Apple SE site [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). If you post there, please delete this as cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: Have you tried `brew install imagemagick` ?

Comment: Thanks harrymc. This does indeed look like progress! Certainly the instructions are comprehensible to me! Understood, Peregrino69. I doubt I'll need to post again but, if I do, I'll delete this one.

Comment: As many other Catalina users have searched for similar information and may find this I'd like to say that the above suggestion by harrymc took care of everything. I didn't need to answer one question or enter another command.